# Символ $ в json ответе (ASP.NET WebAPI)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Есть ASP.NET Web API
Есть контроллер на получение данных

Код:

```
 public class GetCompaniesController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: api/GetCompanies
    public IHttpActionResult GetCompanies()
    {
        var companies = db.Companies.ToList();
        return Ok(new { results = companies });
    }
```

Но возвращает он так данные

```
{"$id":"1","results":[{"$id":"2","Company":{"$id":"3","Clients":[{"$id":"4","Company":{"$ref":"3"},"Id":20,"Email":"nemesises@live.com","UserName":"Евгений","Position":"Developer","Password":"Dontoretto23","From":null,"Subject":null,"Body":null,"CompanyID":20}],"Vacancies":[{"$ref":"2"},{"$id":"5","Company":{"$ref":"3"},"Interwiers":[],"InvitationMails":[],"Interviews":[],"VacancyId":2,"VacancyName":"Тест      ","CompanyID":20},{"$id":"6","Company":{"$ref":"3"},"Interwiers":[],"InvitationMails":[],"Interviews":[],"VacancyId":3,"VacancyName":"Менеджер  ","CompanyID":20},{"$id":"7","Company":{"$ref":"3"},"Interwiers":[],"InvitationMails":[],"Interviews":[],"VacancyId":4,"VacancyName":"Грузчик   ","CompanyID":20}],"CompanyID":20,"CompanyName":"Фокстрот"},"Interwiers":[],"InvitationMails":[],"Interviews":[{"$id":"8","Vacancy":{"$ref":"2"},"Interview_Id":7,"Greeting":"Добрый день!","Detail":"Пройдите интервью","VacancyId":1},{"$id":"9","Vacancy":{"$ref":"2"},"Interview_Id":8,"Greeting":"sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf","Detail":"sdfsdfsdf","VacancyId":1},{"$id":"10","Vacancy":{"$ref":"2"},"Interview_Id":9,"Greeting":null,"Detail":null,"VacancyId":1},{"$id":"11","Vacancy":{"$ref":"2"},"Interview_Id":10,"Greeting":null,"Detail":null,"VacancyId":1},{"$id":"12","Vacancy":{"$ref":"2"},"Interview_Id":11,"Greeting":null,"Detail":null,"VacancyId":1},{"$id":"13","Vacancy":{"$ref":"2"},"Interview_Id":12,"Greeting":null,"Detail":null,"VacancyId":1},{"$id":"14","Vacancy":{"$ref":"2"},"Interview_Id":13,"Greeting":null,"Detail":null,"VacancyId":1}],"VacancyId":1,"VacancyName":"Менеджер  ","CompanyID":20},{"$ref":"5"},{"$ref":"6"},{"$ref":"7"}]}
```

Ка убрать символы?

**АПДЕЙТ**

Значит сделал я DTO

Все окей, но есть одна небольшая загвоздка

Класс например для вакансий такой

```
  public class VacanciesAPI
{
    public int VacancyId { get; set; }
    public string VacancyName { get; set; }

    public int? CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

Так я например могу получить по айдишнику вакансию

```
// GET: api/Vacancies/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Vacancy))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetVacancy(int id)
    {
        var book = await db.Vacancies.Include(b => b.VacancyId).Select(b =>
     new VacanciesAPI()
     {
         VacancyId = b.VacancyId,
         VacancyName = b.VacancyName,
         CompanyId = b.CompanyID

     }).SingleOrDefaultAsync(b => b.VacancyId== id);
        if (book == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(book);
    }
```

Вопрос в том, как переписать этот код, так, чтобы вводить айди компании и получть вакансии

Comment: А Вы уверены, что Вам необходимы все данные скопом из контекста? Просто у Вас тут столько данных... Почему бы Вам не создать объект `DTO (Data Transfer Object)`, с помощью которого Вы будете выгружать данные? Я уверен, что Вам не нужны все данные из полученного результата, а лишь определенные. Таким образом станет понятнее, что именно пошло не так. А так, только предположения есть...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить в WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services


        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Простите, я стесняюсь спросить, а куда это можно добавить в конфиге? Можно поконкретнее?

Comment: @DenisBubnov добавил конкретики.

Comment: "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json;

Получаю такую штуку

Comment: @E.S а теперь нужно создать DTO (Data Transfer Object) как говорил Денис выше.

Comment: ты говоришь об этом? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5

Comment: @E.S Да именно об этом.

Comment: Окей , буду педалить, спасибо большое

Comment: спасибо, разрулил